# Entity Framework Generating Wrong Column with Code First

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code first and building the model below. When I make a call to the model in the context after updating the DB for some reason entity framework is generating a query that has a bad column name. I want to try and correct this. I know I can use data annotations or Fluent API but why is this generating a 1 at the end of the column name. This column is not in the DB or the model.

Model

```
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public int Question_QuestionId { get; set; }       
}
```

Context Call

```
//GetTheAnswers 
var answers = context.Answers.Where(x => x.Question_QuestionId ==   selectedQuestion.QuestionId).ToList();
```

Stack Error

{"Invalid column name 'Question_QuestionId1'."}

Here is the Question Model for review

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; } 
    public virtual LessonSpecification LessonSpecification { get; set; }
    public virtual GrammarStandards GrammarStandard { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: The Question model might be relevant as well.

Comment: I have added the Question model for your review.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is the Answer model? Probably there is also a Question of type Question property. You need to tell EF (using attributes/mapping) that Question_QuestionId property is the foreign key property of the [missing] Answer.Question property.

**EDIT**
Question.Answers needs that on Answer table there is a reference to Question. EF creates a field with name Question_QuestionId on Answer table that conflicts with your Answer.Question_QuestionId property (also for this EF creates a new field).
The name of this new field is Question_QuestionId1.
You can view this looking at DDL statements (EF cfreates the index on the field Question_QuestionId1 because of the relation, also, the relation field is nullable).

```
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Answers] (
 [AnswerId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [AnswerText] text null
, [Question_QuestionId] int not null
, [Question_QuestionId1] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [Answers] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Answers_a5cb86ad] PRIMARY KEY ([AnswerId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE TABLE [Questions] (
 [QuestionId] int not null identity(1,1)
, [QuestionText] text null
, [CorrectAnswer_AnswerId] int null
);
ALTER TABLE [Questions] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Questions_a5cb86ad] PRIMARY KEY ([QuestionId])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_Question_QuestionId1] ON [Answers] ([Question_QuestionId1])
ExecuteNonQuery==========
CREATE INDEX [IX_CorrectAnswer_AnswerId] ON [Questions] ([CorrectAnswer_AnswerId])
```

The strange thing is that with EF 6.1.3 your query is working fine.

Anyway, I think that the best fix in this case is to fix the model i.e.

```
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    //public int Question_QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}


public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context(DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>()
            .HasMany(q => q.Answers)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Question);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }
}
```

The query will be

```
var answers = context.Answers.Where(x => x.Question.QuestionId == selectedQuestion.Question.QuestionId).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the Answer model. I have double check this. The column in the DB is named Question_QuestionId.

Comment: The property Question.Answers requires that EF creates a field on Answer table. But with your model and EF 6.1.3 works fine. Anyway see the answer for more details.

Comment: I have edited the model to what you have put in the answer and it generated this as the migration which looks messed up to me. What are your thoughts?

Comment: DropIndex("dbo.Answers", new[] { "Question_QuestionId1" });
            DropColumn("dbo.Answers", "Question_QuestionId");
            RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Answers", name: "Question_QuestionId1", newName: "Question_QuestionId");
            AlterColumn("dbo.Answers", "Question_QuestionId", c => c.Int());
            CreateIndex("dbo.Answers", "Question_QuestionId");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Answers", "Question_QuestionId1");
            AddForeignKey("dbo.Answers", "Question_QuestionId1", "dbo.Questions", "QuestionId");

Comment: And does it work? I.e. in the last AddForeignKey, the column Question_QuestionId1 does not exists anymore (it has been renamed few statements before). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tired it and I got this error  Invalid column name 'Question_QuestionId1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Question_QuestionId1'

Comment: There is a bug in migration generator. Actually I cant remember how column rename works in SQL Server but if during rename SQL Server fix all related objects it could be enough this: DropColumn("dbo.Answers", "Question_QuestionId"); RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Answers", name: "Question_QuestionId1", newName: "Question_QuestionId");

Comment: The column is named Question_QuestionId still but it is still looking for Question_QuestionId1. I don't know how to get out of this cycle? No matter what i do it seems to keep going back an forth. I guess the column in db has to have a one?

Comment: This is till not solved. I ended up having to have both columns in the DB and it reads from the column with a one on it. I don't know why it is still messing up.

Comment: Are you doing something about mapping? Are you using EF6.1.3? With your models (both of them) works.